# Choosing the right evaluation metric for predicting Session Charges - MAE or RMSE?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using a machine learning model to predict Session Charges. However, I'm unsure about which evaluation metric would be most suitable for my case: Mean Absolute Error (MAE) or Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE).

I understand that MAE gives the average magnitude of the errors, irrespective of their direction, while RMSE emphasizes the magnitude of the errors while considering the squared differences.

Considering that I'm dealing with Session Charges prediction, which metric would be more appropriate in this context? I want to ensure that the evaluation metric provides a comprehensive understanding of the predictive performance and helps me make informed decisions about the model's accuracy.

The objective is to compute metric for a Constant Value, which will be multiplied by the Session Length In Hours, to offer insight to the senior leadership team on the potential outcomes if we opt for the "fast and easy" approach of selecting the best constant value.

Following this, I will present the metric for my predictive model and proceed to make a comparative analysis.

As shown in the screenshot below, we can observe that when considering the Mean Absolute Error (MAE), the ideal constant value to be used would be $60. On the other hand, if we prioritize the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE), then the value of $64.75 would be more effective (if I may use that term).

[image]

Could you kindly assist me in comprehending which metric to utilize and how to accurately interpret the metrics? I am aware that both the Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) are measured on the same scale. However, how can I effectively explain the distinction between the MAE of 29.18$ and the RMSE of 49.36$, and why one may be more suitable in this scenario?

I believe for the MAE, I can state the following: "**By selecting a Constant Value of $60, which is then multiplied by the Session Length In Hours, the average deviation in charges for each new session will be approximately $29.18**". But how can I say something similar for RMSE?